# WKWebView responsive gives the wrong height value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I need to get the height of WKWebView, for ipad is ok but for iPhone is the wrong height

[image: The view for iPhone]

[image: The view for iPad]

The View WKWebView is the part containing Free delivrery from 59e and button discover, the hight i get is the same for ipad and iPhone

Here is the code i use in the function didFinish to get height of the webview :

```
        let script = "document.documentElement.scrollHeight"
                webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (result, error) in
                    if let height = result as? CGFloat {
```

I need to obtain the actual height of the WebView because I'm adjusting the position of the view controller's content below the header, which contains the WebView.

The webview is showing correctly

I tried also retrieve height like this

```
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
  if complete != nil {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
```

I perform all of these adjustments within an SDK independent of any specific views.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!